# what is the best practice for counting per key in java

Tags: java, concurrency

In java I need to count items per key so i thought of using `ConcurrentMap` with key and as value to have `AtomicInteger` however I wonder if there is a better way.  Its not a critical service, its just used for collecting stats, so i don't mind if i'm late 10 seconds with correct stats or something like this.  So i wonder if there is a better practice for it in standard java concurrency, or whether i'm left again with dealing by myself with ConcurrentMap and with `AtomicInteger` (an example which could also solve the problem would be message passing maybe, if yes how could that help me?) (best would be with example...) something which would not have performance issues and would be safe as well, and easy to use, i don't mind about latency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guava provides a [`ConcurrentHashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.html). This is a concurrent [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) implementation, which is effectively a set allowing duplicates. You can `add(E)` and `remove(Object)` as usual, but also retrieve the `count(Object)` of an element in the `Multiset`.

In fact, [this is implemented](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ConcurrentHashMultiset.java#87) using a backing `ConcurrentHashMap<E, AtomicInteger>`, so your practice is perfectly fine. However:

- The `Multiset` interface provides a nicer abstraction, it even extends `Collection`.
- Properly managing those `AtomicIntegers` yourself is a tricky business. Quickly glancing over Guava's code should give you an idea of the challenges that concurrent programming imposes: you need lots of `compareAndSet`s and infinite `while` loops to make sure the correct results come out.

Comment: sounds perfect.  I looked at implementation as you suggested and indeed its not trivial. so if i add 10 items of type Apple it would not store 10 items as its a set only will count it apple to be 10, right?

Comment: @Jason Yup, it'll just have one entry in the map for `"Apple"` containing an `AtomicInteger` with value `10`. The good thing is that you don't have to think about it any longer: all of that is abstracted away and you can just use the `Multiset` interface to work with it.

Comment: thanks, just as a sidenote i see there are discussions about its performance.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/KJuv1P77vRI

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is right direction, so I really don't understand why do you think it is not easy. Just use concurrent-map specific functions. I.e. to update statistics will be:

```
AtomicInteger newCounter = new AtomicInteger(1);
AtomicInteger existingCounter = map.putIfAbsent(key, newCounter);
if(existingCounter != null) 
  existingCounter.incrementAndGet();
```